# What's the best way to have something similar to Protected or Private for an Interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have something as below

```
class XDatabase {
    private val _stateData = MutableStateFlow(XData())
    val stateData: StateFlow<XData> get() = _stateData
}

class YDatabase {
    private val _stateData = MutableStateFlow(YData())
    val stateData: StateFlow<YData> get() = _stateData
}
```

I want to ensure XDatabase and YDatabase conform to each other,

So I make an interface below

```
class XDatabase: Database<XData> {
    override val _stateData = MutableStateFlow(XData())
}

class YDatabase: Database<YData> {
    override val _stateData = MutableStateFlow(YData())
}

interface Database<T> {

    val _stateData: MutableStateFlow<T>
    val stateData: StateFlow<T> get() = _stateData
}
```

But I can no longer set my `_stateData` private nor protected, as an interface in Kotlin doesn't allow that. Is there still a way to set that? (i.e. I want to avoid other class accidentally access `_stateData` from these classes

Comment: The whole point of having an interface is so that you can access `_stateData` from *outside* of `XDatabase` and `YDatabase`, right? e.g. You have used it in the interface `Database<T>`. This means `_stateData` must not be private.

Comment: I don't know a way of doing this, but what would be the purpose of making private members conform to a contract? Private members are an implementation detail. All that matters outside the class is what is public. You could make the StateFlow property part of the interface, and leave it up to implementations whether they want to satisfy it with a backing MutableStateFlow property. Maybe some other implementation wants to satisfy it using `stateIn`. To the class using the interface, there's effectively no difference.

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid the code duplication of `val stateData: StateFlow<XData> get() = _stateData` for every database?

Comment: If that’s what it is, they have something in the works that lets you declare these in a single property by making the type of the backing field accessible within the class. https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/issues/278

Comment: Concretely, requiring that every `Database<T>` be backed by a `MutableStateFlow<T>` creates a brittle codebase. If I want to write a proxy class that provides access to a DB but prohibits certain operations for security reasons, I can satisfy every method of `Database<T>` by delegating to the real class (with appropriate checks in place), but I can't provide a `MutableStateFlow` since I'm really just a proxy. My class *should* be a `Database<T>` (since it has all of the functionality), but it's missing the irrelevant implementation detail that you're requiring of databases.

Answer (score 1):

you can  declaring **_stateData** as private, you ensure that it can only be accessed within the implementing class. The **stateData** property provides a read-only view of the state data that can be accessed externally.

```
interface Database<T> {
    val stateData: StateFlow<T>
    fun updateData(data: T)
}

class XDatabase : Database<XData> {
    private val _stateData = MutableStateFlow(XData())
    override val stateData: StateFlow<XData>
        get() = _stateData

    override fun updateData(data: XData) {
        _stateData.value = data
    }
}

class YDatabase : Database<YData> {
    private val _stateData = MutableStateFlow(YData())
    override val stateData: StateFlow<YData>
        get() = _stateData

    override fun updateData(data: YData) {
        _stateData.value = data
    }
}
```